# ダイアログのオーバーレイ領域の色を変更したい

Tags: android

Activityに`Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`のテーマを適用してダイアログを実装しています。
下図に赤く示しているオーバーレイ領域の色をもう少し暗くしたいと思うのですが、ここの色を指定することはできるのでしょうか？

[image: ダイアログの例]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ここ([Android: Blurring and dimming background windows from dialogs](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-blurring-and-dimming-background-windows-from-dialogs/))にそれっぽい回答がございました。

抜粋します。

> ```
> WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
> lp.dimAmount=0.0f;
> dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
> ```

ダイアログの設定でいけそうな気がします。
"dim" はほの暗いという意味ですね。

**追記**

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);`
が必要でした・・・

Comment: まさにこの方法でできました！0.0だと完全に透明、1.0だと真っ黒になるのですね。
書いていただいたコード例はDialogでしたが、ActivityにDialogテーマを設定した状態でも動きました。

Comment: @niu 
0.0だとやりたいことと逆だとコメントで気づきました。解決されたようで良かった・・・
ググってみると、[ダイアログ表示時に下の画面を暗くしない](http://murakaming.hatenablog.com/entry/20120718/1342587671)というエントリ等、テーマを使用した方法がございますね。こういう方法でも出来るのかと楽しく勉強させていただきました。
編集者の方、修正ありがとうございます。